# Find a partial match in MySQL query with multiple "OR"

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to find partial or full matches in a MySQL query. I am performing queries in multiple tables using 'OR' and need to know whether all conditions have been met or just some of them.

I believe the easiest way to do this would be to create a new column called 'partial' which would either be 0 or 1 (Feel free to correct me if I am wrong).

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
  id, confirmed, name, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressCity, addressPostcode,
  addressLat, addressLon,
  (6371 * acos( cos( radians( '53.649779' ) ) 
              * cos( radians( addressLat ) )
              * cos( radians( addressLon ) - radians( '-1.6026266' ) )
              + sin( radians( '53.649779' ) ) * sin( radians( addressLat ) ) ) 
  ) distance 
FROM TABLE_NAME 
WHERE active = '1' 
  AND deleted = '0' 
  AND 
  (
    id < 0 
   OR 
    id IN 
    (
      SELECT establishmentID 
      FROM appEstablishmentDrinks 
      WHERE active = '1' 
        AND deleted = '0' 
        AND manufacturerDrinkID IN (101) 
      GROUP BY establishmentID 
      HAVING count(distinct manufacturerDrinkID) = 1
    ) 
   OR
    id IN 
    (
      SELECT establishmentID 
      FROM appEstablishmentFacilities 
      WHERE active = '1' 
      AND deleted = '0' 
      AND facilityID IN (37)
    )
  ) 
HAVING distance < '15'
```

Comment: You may extend the data retrieved with statements like: IF(sqlCondition1, 1, 0) AS partial1, IF(sqlCondition2, 1, 0) AS partial2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL `true` = 1 and `false` = 0. So simply add conditions: `(id < 0) + (id in (...)) + (id in (...))` and check whether you got all three matches or less.

```
SELECT
  id, confirmed, name, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressCity, addressPostcode,
  addressLat, addressLon, distance,
  case when count_matches = 3 then 'full' else 'partial' end as matching
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    id, confirmed, name, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressCity, addressPostcode,
    addressLat, addressLon,
    (6371 * acos( cos( radians( 53.649779 ) ) 
                * cos( radians( addressLat ) )
                * cos( radians( addressLon ) - radians( -1.6026266 ) )
                + sin( radians( 53.649779 ) ) * sin( radians( addressLat ) ) ) 
    ) as distance,
    (id < 0 )
     + 
    (
      id IN 
      (
        SELECT establishmentID 
        FROM appEstablishmentDrinks 
        WHERE active = 1 
          AND deleted = 0 
          AND manufacturerDrinkID IN (101) 
        GROUP BY establishmentID 
        HAVING count(distinct manufacturerDrinkID) = 1
      ) 
    )
     +
    (
      id IN 
      (
        SELECT establishmentID 
        FROM appEstablishmentFacilities 
        WHERE active = 1 
        AND deleted = 0 
        AND facilityID IN (37)
      )
    ) as count_matches
  FROM TABLE_NAME 
  WHERE active = 1 
    AND deleted = 0
) x
WHERE distance < 15
AND count_matches > 0;
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your reply. I have tried executing this code in my database but it has given me the following error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id, confirmed, name, addressLine1, addressLine2, addressCity, addressPostcode, ' at line 2

Comment: A typo. `SELECT *  id, confirmed, ...` is of course invalid. Have you not been able to spot that error yourself? "Near 'id ..." pretty much describes where to look. I've removed the `*` now. Please try again.

Comment: Thanks. I did notice that and tried it both with just the * and also without the * but all the column names but still no luck. Error reads: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as distance, (id < 0 ) + ( id IN ( SELE' at line 14

Comment: I had mistakenly deleted a parenthesis. Sorry. I've updated my answer once more.